# How to make the ball appear in a random location

Tags: javascript

I have code that creates a ball and then gives it a random color. Not sure how to make the circle "spawn" in a random location on the screen.

```
      var RADIUS = 120;
      var circle;

function start(){
   circle = new Circle(RADIUS);
   circle.setPosition();
   add(circle);
   setTimer(color, 1000);
}



function color() {
  circle.setColor(Randomizer.nextColor());
}
```

Comment: What are you using, canvas or the dom ?

Comment: canvas is what im using

Answer (score 0):

You could try possitionin with css

```
circle.style.position = "absolute";
circle.style.top = "580px";
circle.style.left = "205px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example, hope you understand.
in your html:

in your script:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_id");
var screen = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawBall()
{
    screen.beginPath();
    screen.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    screen.fillStyle = "#000000";
    screen.fill();
    screen.closePath();
}
```

Now just change the x and y respectively! Goodluck.

Comment: missed something. in html just add your canvas

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old but figured I'd add my 2 cents in case someone lands here for the same question. To make the circle spawn at a random location onload, you would need to randomize the x and y variables. The aim of this is to avoid it spawning at the same place all the time thus making the game boring.

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
```

However, if you leave it like this, you will run into issues where the x and y values result in the ball only moving on a straight cross sectional line along the x-axis or vice versa along the y-axis when the value is too close to the max height or width of the canvas. To work around this issue, create a desired range for the values of your variables using:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
```

Example:

```
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;

var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (700 - 100)) + 100;
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500-100)) + 100;
```